# Не ловит исключение в с++

Tags: c++

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*f)(int,int);

using namespace std;

void function (){

    map<string,f> a;
    a["hello world"] = [](int x, int y){
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
        return x+y;
    };
    try {
        cout << a["hello worl1d"](20,12) << endl;
    }catch (...){
    }
}
```

В результате прекращена работа программы. (Там специально ошибка в ключе.) Ожидалось молчание.

Comment: Разыменование нулевого указателя не является исключением C++, но является неопределённым поведением. Вы видите исключение уровня ОС.

Comment: @ixSci тут всё же не разыменование, а вызов функции.

Comment: А разве в методе самой библиотеки не должна быть проверка на наличие ключа, и в случае его отсутствия бросаться исключение?

Comment: Проверка на наличие ключа есть при обращении через `at`, а не через `operator[]`. См. ответ ниже.

Comment: Здесь есть еще одна щекотливая деталь: а что если ключ даже и сделать правильным? Можно ли вызывать функцию через указатель, полученный от уже сдохшей лямбды? Хотя согласно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026170/lifetime-of-lambda-objects-in-relation-to-function-pointer-conversion здесь проблемы нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор [`[]`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) для `std::map` приводит к созданию нового элемента со значением по умолчанию, если ему передали ещё не существующий ключ. Для возбуждения исключения можно было бы использовать функцию [`at`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at). Однако, лучше вовсе не строить логику на механизме исключений, а просто проверять существование ключа через [`find`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Как уже указано в комментариях к вопросу, в коде происходит исключение уровня ОС (а не языка) при попытке вызова функции по нулевому указателю. Когда указывается несуществующий ранее ключ создается нулевой указатель на функцию и через него идёт попытка сделать вызов с аргументами `(20,12)`. Это и приводит к ошибке (в общем случае - неопределенное поведение).

Answer (score -1):

Ну у меня пишет err:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using f = std::function<int(int,int)>;

void function (){
    std::map<std::string, f> a;
    a["hello world"] = [](int x, int y){
        std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
        return x+y;
    };
    try {
        std::cout << a["hello worl1d"](20,12) << std::endl;
    }catch (...) {
      std::cout<< "err" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main(){
  function();
}
```

Comment: Потому, что Вы используете `std::function`, а ТС - классический указатель на функцию. `std::function` генерит `std::bad_function_call`, который и перехватывается через `... `.

Comment: У вас видимо functional генерирует исключение. А мне интересно почему map молит.